# Finding $E(X-Y)^2$ given a joint probability table

Tags: probability

As the question states, given a joint probability table, I need to find $E[X-Y]^2$.

I am not sure how to approach the questions, I tried two approaches:

**Approach 1**

$E[X-Y]$ is $E[X]-E[Y]$ by the properties of expectation. After this I did not know how to find $E[X-Y]^2$.

**Approach 2**

$E[X-Y]^2$

$=E[X^2-2XY-Y^2]$

$=E[X^2] -2E[XY]-E[Y^2]$

From this I found $E[X^2]$ by using the marginal probability found and then squaring the X and multiplying its probability. As done normally. I did the same for $E[Y^2]$.

For $2E[XY] = 2\cdot E[X] \cdot E[Y]$

The answer I got is wrong and I am not sure where to start debugging

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? Do you mean $E[ (X-Y)^2 ]$ or $(E[X-Y])^2$ those two are not the same.

Comment: I mean the former. Sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$E[(X-Y)^2]=E[X^2]-2E[XY]+E[Y^2]$.  Your last term had a - not + plus.

Answer (score 0):

$E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$ if and only if the covariance between X and Y is zero.

$E(XY) = \sum_{i = 0}^n\sum_{j = 0}^n P(X = x_i,Y = y_i)y_ix_i $

Comment: Yeah,you're right. Thanks.